# Usage of Escape char and Text Enclosure

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

What is the use of Escape char and Text Enclosure in tFileOutputDelimited component and How can we use them??

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, consider the below example from CSV file

```
bookId,bookname,description,authorname
1,Grammer,book that has details about grammer,author1
2,Special Characters, book that describes about some escape characters like \", punctuations and special characters ,etc.,author2
3,Mathematics, book that has mathematical operations like addition +, subtraction -, multiplication *, division / etc, author3
```

I have created a simple job like below

[image]

In the above sample, character comma `","` is the delimiter. But there are **some commas in between the data**.

The data that is written to CSV file will look like below,

[image]

Now When I **read the data from that file** I will get below data

```
.------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------.
|                                                       tLogRow_3                                                       |
|=-----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------=|
|bookId|bookName          |description                                            |author                               |
|=-----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------=|
|1     |Grammer           |book that has details about grammer                    |author1                              |
|2     |Special Characters|book that describes about some escape characters like "| punctuations and special characters |
|3     |Mathematics       |book that has mathematical operations like addition +  | subtraction -                       |
'------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------'
```

If you notice, **some data are missing in the log for `"author"` column**.

This is because of the **comma in between the data**. To avoid it `Text Enclosure` option is used. Also there is a **escape character in the data**, which is **`\"`**. In the file it will be printed as **`"`**. If `Text Enclosure` has value as **`"""`**, then you need to escape the character **`"`** which is present inside the data. To do this, you have to use `Escape char` option, like below

[image]

Now the output that I got is

[image]

When I read this data, I will get data like below,

```
.------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------.
|                                                                tLogRow_3                                                                |
|=-----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------=|
|bookId|bookName          |description                                                                                            |author |
|=-----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------=|
|1     |Grammer           |book that has details about grammer                                                                    |author1|
|2     |Special Characters|book that describes about some escape characters like ", punctuations and special characters ,etc.     |author2|
|3     |Mathematics       |book that has mathematical operations like addition +, subtraction -, multiplication *, division / etc.|author3|
'------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------'
```

If you notice, **no data is lost**.

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: hello Viki888, you did not perform any changes to get the output second time.. can you please provide me the changes if u did anything...

Comment: The changes that I did is, i have `enabled the CSV options in the tFileOutputDelimited component` which I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank u  Viki888 .... but when we are using tFixedflowInput component that output is coming.....otherwise (i.e tFileInputDelimited..) it wont produce required result

Comment: In that case, for `tFileInputDelimited` you have to enable `CSV options`.